# Atomic 16-Byte operations on x86_64

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly

Are the following 16 byte atomic operations correctly implemented? Are there any better alternatives?

```
typedef struct {
    uintptr_t low;
    uintptr_t high;
} uint128_atomic;


uint128_atomic load_relaxed(uint128_atomic const *atomic)
{
    uint128_atomic ret;
    asm volatile("xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
                 "xor %%ebx, %%ebx\n"
                 "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n"
                 "xor %%edx, %%edx\n"
                 "lock; cmpxchg16b %1"
                 : "=A"(ret)
                 : "m"(*atomic)
                 : "cc", "rbx", "rcx");
    return ret;
}

bool cmpexch_weak_relaxed(
    uint128_atomic *atomic,
    uint128_atomic *expected,
    uint128_atomic desired)
{
    bool matched;
    uint128_atomic e = *expected;
    asm volatile("lock; cmpxchg16b %1\n"
                 "setz %0"
                 : "=q"(matched), "+m"(atomic->ui)
                 : "a"(e.low), "d"(e.high), "b"(desired.low), "c"(desired.high)
                 : "cc");
    return matched;
}

void store_relaxed(uint128_atomic *atomic, uint128_atomic val)
{
    uint128_atomic old = *atomic;
    asm volatile("lock; cmpxchg16b %0"
                 : "+m"(*atomic)
                 : "a"(old.low), "d"(old.high), "b"(val.low), "c"(val.high)
                 : "cc");
}
```

For a full working example, checkout:

https://godbolt.org/g/CemfSg

Updated implementation can be found here: https://godbolt.org/g/vGNQG5

Comment: Is the syntax of a lock prefix really `lock;`?

Comment: @harold I don't think it really matters. You can do it with and without semicolon. The gnu assembler is incredibly relaxed.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the C11 atomic intrinsics?

Comment: @zwol C11 atomics reside in `libatomic` and incur a DSO call penalty on every call.

Comment: I might change load_relaxed to use `"b"(0), "c"(0)` as input constraints instead of clobbers+xor. This allows them to be re-used if (say) load_relaxed is called twice consecutively. Similarly, try using `"a"(0), "d"(0)"` as input constraints and remove all the xors. This allows the compiler to zero these registers interleaved into earlier code. For cmpexch_weak_relaxed, [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands) instead of setz might avoid unnecessary instructions if the function is inlined. And *maybe* use `volatile` on the `atomic` param. Or use atomics.

Comment: I forgot to mention that store_relaxed assumes the store will always occur.  If it doesn't (unlikely, but certainly possible), rax/rdx will get changed, but you didn't tell the compiler that might happen.  It occurs to me that if you do all the things I just mentioned, won't all 3 cases really end up being exactly the same 1 line asm statement?  Using @cc should allow any unneeded flags work to be optimized away if unneeded, so the constraints are even the same.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks for the hints! They're almost the same, just oh-so-slightly different. I wrote up a new implementation, fixing all the minor mistakes I did before: https://godbolt.org/g/vGNQG5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with the following implementation, after applying all the suggestions from [@PeterCordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), [@David Wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189500/david-wohlferd) and [@prl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422330/prl). Thanks a lot!

```
struct _uint128_atomic {
    volatile uint64_t low;
    volatile uint64_t high;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef struct _uint128_atomic uint128_atomic;


bool
cmpexch_weak_relaxed(
    uint128_atomic *atomic,
    uint128_atomic *expected,
    uint128_atomic desired)
{
    bool matched;
    uint128_atomic e = *expected;
    asm volatile("lock cmpxchg16b %1"
                 : "=@ccz"(matched), "+m"(*atomic), "+a"(e.low), "+d"(e.high)
                 : "b"(desired.low), "c"(desired.high)
                 : "cc");
    if (!matched)
        *expected = e;
    return matched;
}


uint128_atomic
load_relaxed(uint128_atomic const *atomic)
{
    uint128_atomic ret = {0, 0};
    asm volatile("lock cmpxchg16b %1"
                 : "+A"(ret)
                 : "m"(*atomic), "b"(0), "c"(0)
                 : "cc");
    return ret;
}


void
store_relaxed(uint128_atomic *atomic, uint128_atomic val)
{
    uint128_atomic old = *atomic;
    while (!cmpexch_weak_relaxed(atomic, &old, val))
        ;
}
```

Please keep in mind that the implementation is GCC specific, and will not work on `clang`. The implementation of GCCs inline assembly in `clang` is suboptimal at best, and garbage at worst.
The GCC implementation can also be found on Godbolt's Compiler Explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/g/dpMu39).
A suboptimal, but working, `clang` implementation can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/g/PeQJGB).

Comment: `volatile` members of a non-`volatile` struct probably don't do what you expect.  Just like `_Atomic` on struct members, it's probably ignored during struct assignment, and would only have an effect when accessing that member separately.  Good idea to add alignment to the struct type, though!  I think we all forgot to mention that, and it could have led to performance disasters on cache-line spilts.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the C11 atomic intrinsics?

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

inline __uint128_t load_relaxed(_Atomic __uint128_t *obj)
{
  return atomic_load_explicit(obj, memory_order_relaxed);
}

inline _Bool cmpexch_weak_relaxed(_Atomic __uint128_t *obj,
                                  __uint128_t *expected,
                                  __uint128_t desired)
{
  return atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(obj, expected, desired,
    memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

This compiles to more-or-less the assembly you wrote, using clang 4.0.1 and `-march=native`.  But, unlike what you wrote, the compiler actually understands what's going on, so code generation *around* these functions will be correct.  There is, as far as I know, no way to annotate a GNU-style assembly insert to tell the compiler that it has the semantics of an atomic operation.

Comment: I think the OP's code is safe, because of `asm volatile`.  They're not worried about compile-time reordering, because it's `relaxed`.  The only possible danger is compiler-generated access to the memory other than with the `asm volatile` code, which could be avoided with `volatile uint128_atomic const *atomic`.

Comment: Note that gcc 7 changed how 128-bit atomic objects are treated.  It no longer inlines a `lock cmpxchg16b` even if you compile with `-mcx16`, instead always calling libgcc.  The current libgcc implementation does use `lock cmpxchg16b` on machines that support it (first-gen K8 didn't).  See the reasoning: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html, and note that `atomic<__int128>` is reported as not lock-free, because load/store are much slower than what that normally implies.  This is why the OP is reporting calls to libatomic.  (Maybe link `libatomic` statically as a hack?)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, they really should've coordinated that change with the LLVM people.  I do also see calls to __atomic_load_16 and __atomic_compare_exchange_16 generated by GCC 7.3 on my computer.  It's not clear to me why that patch affected `atomic_compare_exchange_*`, either.

Comment: They wanted the option of picking a different strategy entirely for atomic 16-byte objects.  e.g. making them use a mutex.  So they can't ever inline `lock cmpxchg16b`.  It doesn't seem like a very great design decision.  (Apparently [the old `__sync` builtins can still inline it with `-mcx16`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80878#c6)).  **Probably the best summary of discussion / reasons for gcc7's not inlining `lock cmpxchg16b` is in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84563**

Answer (score 2):

No, you need "+a" and "+d" in cmpexch_weak_relaxed and store_relaxed.

Other than that, I don't see any problems. (I compared to my own implementations in working software.)

As far as improvements, I suggest

```
uint128_atomic load_relaxed(uint128_atomic const *atomic)
{
    uint128_atomic ret = { 0, 0 };
    asm volatile("lock; cmpxchg16b %1"
                 : "+A"(ret)
                 : "m"(*atomic), "b"(0), "c"(0)
                 : "cc");
    return ret;
}
```

(I see that David Wohlferd also made this suggestion in a comment.)

Comment: I think the OP also missed making some of the CAS operands `+`.  Your testing probably didn't see any contention that made CAS retry, or it happened to compile to working asm code by accident.  (Also, the `setz` could be replaced with a gcc6 flag output operand).

Comment: @petercordes "CAS operands +" - I thought so at first, but the only routine that omits it (load_relaxed), will only write the value (0) if the current value is 0.  Is it "writing" (from the compiler's point of view) if the only possible value it might write is the one that's already there?  And like I said above, by the time you clean everything up, there really is only 1 asm statement here that all 3 routines should use.  The ccz (the only parameter not used by all 3) should get optimized away (in all 3 cases) if unused.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I should have been more specific.   The [`lock cmpxchg16b`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CMPXCHG8B_CMPXCHG16B) in `cmpexch_weak_relaxed` will update `rdx:rax` if the CAS fails (and this is necessary in a CAS retry loop, but `cmpexch_weak_relaxed` is buggy and fails to update `*expected` except by accident from using the wrong constraints.)  I should write up my own answer now that I see more of this stuff that nobody else has mentioned yet. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Ahh, fair enough.  I was just looking at the memory operand.  Still, I believe that load_relaxed and store_relaxed are just thin wrappers around a correctly written cmpexch_weak_relaxed.

Comment: xD, /facepalm.  I think I remember reading that, but forgot about it after thinking of something else.  >.<  But anyway, notice that the function doesn't update `*expected` with the new value of `e`.  It should be using `"+A" (*expected)`, or doing `*expected = e`.  Also, the store function doesn't retry on CAS failure.

Comment: @Peter, I noticed those but since he didn’t describe the expected behavior I didn’t mention them.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PeterCordes. I wrote up a following all your suggestions. Thanks for the tip with gcc6's flag output operand, way better! https://godbolt.org/g/vGNQG5

Comment: @Leandros: Yup, I that fixes all the bugs I noticed, including using `uintptr_t` when you really meant `uint64_t`.  ([Linux's x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) has 32-bit pointers in long mode, so your old version could have compiled and assembled to silently-wrong code that writes outside the objects gcc is expecting. (x32 is excellent if you need double-word atomic objects for pointer+ABA-counter or whatever, because 8-byte atomic load/store doesn't need cmpxchg in 64-bit mode, only actually RMW ops.  So gcc/clang do a good job with C11 atomics.)

Comment: @Leandros: you should write that up as an answer, if you have the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes good idea! Just posted my answer with my findings.